# In Sumo Logic, how do I get a list of folders off the root folder?

Tags: sumologic

Using the Sumo Logic API, `/api/v2/content/folders/{id}` works and gives me the parentId. hitting the same endpoint for a folder off the root folder gives a parentId. however hitting the same endpoint with that id errors with "Content with the given ID does not exist."

When I hit `/api/v2/folders/global` it returns an id. every time I hit the endpoint it gives me a different id. trying to use any of those ids at `/api/v2/content/folders/{id}` also gives the error "Content with the given ID does not exist."

I'm trying to write a script that will return the Sumo Logic ID of a folder from a user-defined path. e.g. `get_sumo_id -p "/products/someapp/monitoring"`

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. I hadn’t read the docs well enough. The id returned from `/api/v2/folders/global` is a job id, not a folder id. You wait until it's done and check for success using `/api/v2/folders/global/<job id>/status`. if successful you can retrieve `/api/v2/folders/global/<job id>/result`.